# How to handle dynamic addition of Views

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am creating an Android app which has questions and the users can answer them by choosing from the provided two options. They also have the option of adding more options dynamically (at max three more). I am submitting the post to the database like this.

```
public void sendPost(View v){

        String titlePost = etTitlePost.getText().toString().trim();
        String textPost = etTextPost.getText().toString().trim();
        String option1 = etOption1.getText().toString().trim();
        String option2 = etOption2.getText().toString().trim();

        String option3 = null, option4 = null, option5 = null;

        if(findViewById(R.id.etOption3)!=null){
            EditText etOption3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etOption3);
            option3 = etOption3.getText().toString().trim();
        }

        if(findViewById(R.id.etOption4)!=null){
            EditText etOption4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etOption4);
            option4 = etOption4.getText().toString().trim();
        }

        if(findViewById(R.id.etOption5)!=null){
            EditText etOption5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etOption5);
            option5 = etOption5.getText().toString().trim();
        }

        if(!titlePost.isEmpty() && !textPost.isEmpty() && !option1.isEmpty() && !option2.isEmpty()){

            if( option3 !=null && !option3.isEmpty()){
                if( option4 !=null && !option4.isEmpty()){
                    if( option5 !=null && !option5.isEmpty()){
                        submitPost(titlePost, textPost, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5);
                    }
                    else{
                        submitPost(titlePost, textPost, option1, option2, option3, option4);

                    }
                }
                else {
                    submitPost(titlePost, textPost, option1, option2, option3);

                }
            }
            else {
                submitPost(titlePost, textPost, option1, option2);
            }
        }

        else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill everything!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
```

I could do this because the number of options were limited. If the total number of options weren't known at the compile time, what would have been the `best and most efficient` possible way to accomplish this task?

Also I am adding the EditTexts dynamically like something below.

```
    int o=3;
    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

public void addOption(View v){


        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if(o<6){
                etNewOption = new EditText(this);
                etNewOption.setId(o);     
                l.addView(etNewOption, o+1, params);
            }
```

How can I set their ids to some strings?

Comment: This looks like a job for a ListView.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a class called `View` then create another class called `Controller`.

In your main method, you iterate through a loop, create a view and add it to the controller.

When you're out of the loop, you can access a desired view:

```
controller.getViewByName("Option3");
```

This would be a method in your controller which would look for a view with that identifier.

```
Controller c = new Controller();
for (i = 0; i < amountOfViews; i++)
{
  //some work
  View v = New View(...);
  c.add(v);
}
```

You need to create your own custom methods in controller and assign their id's and create methods so that you can fetch the desired view by id. A `HashMap` to store the structure would be ideal, i believe in this case.

Does that answer your question?

**EDIT:** That was a simple example, but instead of doing a for loop. Because you don't know how many views you have.

I would use an infinite while loop to fetch a view, when it comes back as null you break out of the while loop and you have your ArrayList or HashMap or Custom Structure Filled with views.